# return first error in customized formatted in laravel 5.5 form requests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Before **laravel 5.5** I used a form request like this with a customized format :

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;

class StoreProductRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize ()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules ()
    {
        return [
            'title'      => 'required',
            'desc'       => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function response (array $errors)
    {
        return response()->json($errors, 200);
    }

    protected function formatErrors (Validator $validator)
    {
        $result = ['success' => false, 'msg' => $validator->errors()->first()];
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Means when an error occured, only the first error returned as a json format like this :

```
{
   "success" : "false",
   "msg" : "title field is required "
}
```

But seem that in **laravel 5.5** in this way could not format error like this.

Now I want to return error exactly same format I mentioned above in json format but I do not know How can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality was changed in Laravel 5.5. [From the upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade) "A Note On Form Requests":

> If you were customizing the response format of an individual form request, you should now override the `failedValidation` method of that form request, and throw an HttpResponseException instance containing your custom response

Your updated Form Request might look something like this (pseudo-code, not tested):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

class StoreProductRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title'      => 'required',
            'desc'       => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(
            response()->json(['success' => false, 'msg' => $validator->errors()->first()], 400)
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected function formatErrors (Validator $validator)
{
    $result = ['success' => false, 'msg' => $validator->errors()];
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Aken Roberts answer. Since this is an error response for a form, I use the error key (input field name) to display the error beside the input.
You can get the first error key from the `keys` method. With Laravel 5.7 this works as expected:

```
public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(
        response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'error' => (object) [
                $validator->errors()->keys()[0] => $validator->errors()->first()
            ]
        ], 400)
    );
}
```